# if selected value = 1 do this, if selected value = 2 do this

Tags: php, forms, post, curl, selection

im using a selection form element, to ask the user, which function he wants to use.

My problem actually is the following:

1 form element:

```
<form action="php/questhandler.php" method="post" parsley-validate="" novalidate="">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quest</label>
            <select name="inputQuest" id="inputQuest" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Please select a quest...</option>
                <option value="1">PHPcode1</option>
                <option value="2">PHPcode2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:11px;" class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Redeem Quest</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

2. PHP document

   ```
   <?php

   $choose = $_POST['inputQuest'];

   // SELECTION 1
   if($choose = '1'){
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'POSTURLHERE');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'POSTFIELDSHERE');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $global['cookie']);
       $response = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);

       echo "FUNCTION 1 SUCCESSFULL";
   }

   // SELECTION 2
   if($choose = '2'){
       $startValue = 0;
       $endValue = 10;

       for($startValue; $startValue <= $endValue; $startValue++){
           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'POSTURLHERE');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'POSTFIELDSHERE');
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $global['cookie']);
           $response = curl_exec($ch);
           curl_close($ch);

           echo "FUNCTION 2 got " .$startValue. " times added.";
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

My question is the following: How could i make the PHP code just run the selected code which got posted from the form element?

I tried using the if parameters as you guys can see in the Code, but it still does run both codes.

Comment: `=` is an __assignment__ operator, `==` or `===` are the __comparison__ operators in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$choose == '1'` and `$choose == '2'` - This way is checking to see if the variable matches the value exactly

Comment: I will :) 20 minutes from now